# How to change the line traffic color in Google map - Angular

Tags: css, angular, typescript, google-maps

I am making an application as shown in the below link.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/travel-marker-angular-agm

I want to change the line traffic color to blue.

I tried using `strokeColor: "blue"` but it didn't work!

My code:

```
calcRoute() {
    this.line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeColor: "blue",
      path: [],
      map: this.map
    });

    const start = new google.maps.LatLng(51.513237, -0.099102);
    const end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514786, -0.080799);
    const request = {
        origin:start,
        destination:end,
        travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,

    };

    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    this.directionsService.route(request, (response, status) => {
      // Empty response as API KEY EXPIRED
      console.log(response);
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (let i=0;i<legs.length; i++) {
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (let j=0; j<steps.length; j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            for (let k=0; k<nextSegment.length; k++) {
              this.line.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            }
          }
        }
        this.initRoute();
      }
    });
  }

  // mock directions api
  mockDirections() {
    const locationArray = locationData.map(l => new google.maps.LatLng(l[0], l[1]));
    this.line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      path: [],
      map: this.map
    });
    locationArray.forEach(l => this.line.getPath().push(l));

    const start = new google.maps.LatLng(51.513237, -0.099102);
    const end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514786, -0.080799);

    const startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: start, map: this.map, label: 'A'});
    const endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({position: end, map: this.map, label: 'B'});
    this.initRoute();
  } ......
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a hex value to pass the color... e.g.: `strokeColor: '#0000FF'`

```
  mockDirections() {
    const locationArray = locationData.map(
      l => new google.maps.LatLng(l[0], l[1])
    );
    this.line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeColor: '#0000FF',    <---Here
      path: [],
      map: this.map
    });
    locationArray.forEach(l => this.line.getPath().push(l));

    const start = new google.maps.LatLng(51.513237, -0.099102);
    const end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514786, -0.080799);

    const startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: start,
      map: this.map,
      label: "A"
    });
    const endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: end,
      map: this.map,
      label: "B"
    });
    this.initRoute();
  }
```

To center the map based on the car's location you can update the center of the map with the position of the car. To do so, you can use the event listeners that are defined in the code (that is commented out as well), and the update the center of the map in the listener..
See example below; there are three points in the code indicated with 'HERE'

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
import { MouseEvent, AgmMap } from "@agm/core";
import {
  TravelMarker,
  TravelMarkerOptions,
  TravelData,
  TravelEvents,
  EventType
} from "travel-marker";
import locationData from "./loc.json";

declare var google: any;

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.scss"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  // google maps zoom level
  zoom: number = 15;

  // initial center position for the map
  lat: number = 51.512802;
  lng: number = -0.091324;

  map: any;
  line: any;
  directionsService: any;
  marker: TravelMarker = null;

  // speedMultiplier to control animation speed
  speedMultiplier = 1;

  onMapReady(map: any) {
    console.log(map);
    this.map = map;
    // this.calcRoute();
    this.mockDirections();
    this.initEvents();     <---Here (uncommented this so listeners can be invoked)
  }

  /**
   *                  IMPORTANT NOTICE
   *  Google stopped its FREE TIER for Directions service.
   *  Hence the below route calculation will not work unless you provide your own key with directions api enabled
   *
   *  Meanwhile, for the sake of demo, precalculated value will be used
   */

  // get locations from direction service
  calcRoute() {
    this.line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      path: [],
      map: this.map
    });

    const start = new google.maps.LatLng(51.513237, -0.099102);
    const end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514786, -0.080799);
    const request = {
      origin: start,
      destination: end,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.BICYCLING
    };
    this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    this.directionsService.route(request, (response, status) => {
      // Empty response as API KEY EXPIRED
      console.log(response);
      if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
        var legs = response.routes[0].legs;
        for (let i = 0; i < legs.length; i++) {
          var steps = legs[i].steps;
          for (let j = 0; j < steps.length; j++) {
            var nextSegment = steps[j].path;
            for (let k = 0; k < nextSegment.length; k++) {
              this.line.getPath().push(nextSegment[k]);
            }
          }
        }
        this.initRoute();
      }
    });
  }

  /**
   *                  IMPORTANT NOTICE
   *  Google stopped its FREE TIER for Directions service.
   *  Hence the below route calculation will not work unless you provide your own key with directions api enabled
   *
   *  Meanwhile, for the sake of demo, precalculated value will be used
   */

  // mock directions api
  mockDirections() {
    const locationArray = locationData.map(
      l => new google.maps.LatLng(l[0], l[1])
    );
    this.line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      path: [],
      map: this.map
    });
    locationArray.forEach(l => this.line.getPath().push(l));

    const start = new google.maps.LatLng(51.513237, -0.099102);
    const end = new google.maps.LatLng(51.514786, -0.080799);

    const startMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: start,
      map: this.map,
      label: "A"
    });
    const endMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: end,
      map: this.map,
      label: "B"
    });
    this.initRoute();
  }

  // initialize travel marker
  initRoute() {
    const route = this.line.getPath().getArray();

    // options
    const options: TravelMarkerOptions = {
      map: this.map, // map object
      speed: 50, // default 10 , animation speed
      interval: 10, // default 10, marker refresh time
      speedMultiplier: this.speedMultiplier,
      markerOptions: {
        title: "Travel Marker",
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        icon: {
          url: "https://i.imgur.com/eTYW75M.png",
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels high.
          animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
          // size: new google.maps.Size(256, 256),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(128, 128),
          // The origin for this image is (0, 0).
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at (0, 32).
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(53, 110)
        }
      }
    };

    // define marker
    this.marker = new TravelMarker(options);

    // add locations from direction service
    this.marker.addLocation(route);
    this.map.setCenter(this.marker.getPosition()); <---HERE (initialize center of map)

    setTimeout(() => this.play(), 2000);
  }

  // play animation
  play() {
    this.marker.play();
  }

  // pause animation
  pause() {
    this.marker.pause();
  }

  // reset animation
  reset() {
    this.marker.reset();
  }

  // jump to next location
  next() {
    this.marker.next();
  }

  // jump to previous location
  prev() {
    this.marker.prev();
  }

  // fast forward
  fast() {
    this.speedMultiplier *= 2;
    this.marker.setSpeedMultiplier(this.speedMultiplier);
  }

  // slow motion
  slow() {
    this.speedMultiplier /= 2;
    this.marker.setSpeedMultiplier(this.speedMultiplier);
  }

  initEvents() {
    this.marker.event.onEvent((event: EventType, data: TravelData) => {
      console.log(event, data);
      this.map.setCenter(this.marker.getPosition());  <--- Here (updates center of map)
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @jetvalorant on the stackblitz you provided is working when you change it. see edited answer

Comment: also, the calcRoute method is not invoked anywhere as its commented out (at least on the code you provided)

Comment: glad to help ;)

Comment: we can find a function to make map move with car like gps animation in google maps ? @Peter

Comment: you mean like focus on the car?

Comment: exactly like this : https://azuremapscodesamples.azurewebsites.net/Animations/Animate%20a%20GPS%20trace.html @Peter

Comment: yeah you can do it by changing the center of the map to match the location of the car

Comment: Any example or any code or any think help me to do this please ! @Peter

Comment: will update the answer above to include this as well

Comment: yes please !! you so amazing bro and you help me a lot. @Peter

Comment: that great but i want in same timechange view of map to be like this exapmle in link.

Comment: Given the example above; you could use it and play around to achieve what you want